# Unequal column height with bootstrap4 Flex

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, alignment, bootstrap-4

I'm using Boostrap4 and trying to make a simple 4*4 grid of divs which has an image and some text. Initially, I attempted to use 6 columns nested inside a single row and that ended up looking like:

[image]

So the issue here is that the picture isn't centered in the column. So next I used `text-center`on the row. This worked but now the text is also centered when I want it to be aligned to the left of the image:

[image]

So I ended up scrapping all of this and got rid of bootstrap rows and columns and tried to use bootstrap's flex classes. This has the general structure:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div> image and text content here </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this works nicely except that since the column heights can vary, the row doesn't look aligned:

[image]

What is a way to fix this? What is the best practice when attempting to make a grid of divs like this, using bootstrap4.

Since someone wanted to see the entire code.

```
<div class="row border justify-content-around border-r flex-wrap">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column border-r"> <!-- this is repeated twice more for each column -->
                        <div class="tile">
                            <a href="./wanderlust.html">
                                <img class ="thumbnail img-fluid" src ="images/wanderlust.jpg"/>
                                <h5 class=" thumbnail-title"> Wanderlust </h5>
                                <p class=" thumbnail-subtitle"> design research + UX + UI <br> +  programming </p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tile">
                            <a href ="behavior-change.html">
                                <img class ="thumbnail img-fluid" src ="images/breakfast.jpg">
                                <h5 class="thumbnail-title"> Behavior Change </h5>
                                <p class="thumbnail-subtitle"> design research</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: Dude Add a fixed height to column if know the text is not more than 2 or 3 lines. If not then bootstrap use "masonary layout" --- "Check CARD COLUMNS" - https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/

Comment: @ZimSystem i added the code.

Comment: @MontyGoldy You probably should link the stable release docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `row` and `col-*`s and align `img`s at the center of the the columns using the `d-block` and `mx-auto` classes.

```html
<img class="thumbnail img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="images/wanderlust.jpg" />
```

`d-block` sets its display to `block` and `mx-auto` sets its `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`.